# How to add border bottom for last row of table in each page in mpdf and extend last row to the footer

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, mpdf

I used `mpdf` in Laravel to create an invoice with an HTML table that has a header and footer.

The table breaks automatically when it reaches the footer, but the border at the bottom of the last row is missing like in the image below:

[image: mpdf border problem]

How can I add the border at the bottom of the last row on each page? Also, I need to extend the height of the last row to the start of the footer on each page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.